# wpf trigger property IsPressed not working correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

When I click a `Button`, the image in it must change and remain changed. I tried to use the `Triggers` on the `Button` `Style`, binding the image to the `IsPressed` property, but when the `Button` is released, the image returns the previous one. Please help.

```
<Button Content="Easy Locate" Height="20" Width="85" Margin="0,2,0,0">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0">
                  <Image Source="/AltusClient;component/Images/waiting.png"
                         Height="20"
                         Width="25"/>
                </Border>
                <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                  </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `IsPressed` state persists only as long as you continute pressing the button? That's what `IsPressed` means. Are you saying you want to change the button content *permanently* when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I want. How  I do that.

Comment: I think you should be able to do that with a storyboard in the trigger EnterActions, but it's a bit of a pain. Back in a while.

Comment: Can you please help if you have a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a button that works the way you want. You can easily switch the button back to its default state by adding another `Trigger` to set its `Tag` property to `null`, an empty string, or absolutely anything in the world other than `"ButtonHasBeenPressed"`.

```
<Button Content="Button Content">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate 
                    x:Key="PressedTemplate" 
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Border 
                        Background="LightSkyBlue" 
                        BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" 
                        BorderThickness="4"
                        >
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="Replace this TextBlock with your own content" 
                            Foreground="ForestGreen" 
                            />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- 
                We can't set Template directly with DiscreteObjectKeyFrame because 
                "Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads".

                So instead we kludge it by setting Tag and putting a trigger on that. 
                -->
                <Trigger 
                    Property="Tag" 
                    Value="ButtonHasBeenPressed"
                    >
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Template" 
                        Value="{StaticResource PressedTemplate}" 
                        />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <!-- 
                    Values set by a Trigger setter are automatically rolled 
                    back when the Trigger condition no longer applies. This 
                    is not true of values applied by a Storyboard in an enter 
                    action. 
                    -->
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag"
                                    >
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                        KeyTime="00:00:00" 
                                        Value="ButtonHasBeenPressed" 
                                        />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank Ed let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use code-behind.

Suppose the Button is:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">
  <Image Source="/Image1.png"/>
</Button>
```

Then, the code behind could be:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = sender as Button;

    if (b == null)
        return;

    var image = new Image { Source = GetImageSource(), };

    b.Content = image;
}

private BitmapImage GetImageSource()
{
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();

    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.UriSource = new Uri("/Image2.png", UriKind.Relative);
    imageSource.EndInit();

    return imageSource;
}
```

This is a simplify version, that loads the new image every time the user click. If you want to avoid unnecessary secondary loading, you can set a private flag like `private bool _imageSet;` and set it on the `Button_Click` method.

You can also load the new image early on the Window's (or UserControl's) initialization.

Eventually, I suggest you to put all the images in a `ResourceDictionary` and call them throughout the application via `StaticResource` `Key`, and not using the URIs all around. But that's another topic.